# Is there way to implement a pinch-off zoom functionality with touch event in android?

Tags: android, touch-event, pinchzoom, pinch

> I have a load static image in image-view layout & I want to implement pinch-off zoom functionality with touch-event for particular image?

> In google map having similar kind of functionality and In google map we have option to pinch-off zoom into particular location and also have a click to set marker in particular location so this way want to integration functionality of zoom-in and zoom-out with touch event of particular image?

Comment: Yes there is a way and several open source libraries have done it, so you can spy on their code. There's e.g. [https://github.com/martinwithaar/PinchToZoom](https://github.com/martinwithaar/PinchToZoom)

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for issues/problems with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.